# EF adding duplicate records into lookup/reference table

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have 3 tables, 
1. AttributeTypes (Columns: AttributeId (PK), AttributeName, ..)
2. Location (Columns: locationId (PK), LocationName, ...)
3. LocationAttributeType (Columns: locationId (FK), AttributeId (FK))

Whenever I am trying to insert new location record along with its attribute type from GUI, it should create new record for Table- **Location** and **LocationAttributeType**. But EF trying to add new record in Table- **AttributeTypes** as well, which is just used as reference table and should not add new/duplicate records in it. How can I prevent that?

here is my code,

The model which GUI sends is,

```
public class LocationDataModel
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<AttributeTypeDataModel> AssignedAttributes = new List<AttributeTypeDataModel>();
}
public class AttributeTypeDataModel
{
    protected AttributeTypeDataModel() {}

    public AttributeTypeDataModel(int id) { this.Id = id; }

    public AttributeTypeDataModel(int id, string name)
        : this(id)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<LocationDataModel> Locations { get; set; }
  }
```

The Entities created by EF are,

```
public partial class Location
{
    public Location()
    {
        this.AttributeTypes = new List<AttributeType>();
    }

    public Location(int campusId, string code)
        : this()
    {
        CampusId = campusId; Code = code;
    }


    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CampusId { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AttributeType> AttributeTypes { get; set; }
```

}

```
public partial class AttributeType
{
    public AttributeType()
    {
        this.Locations = new List<Location>();
    }

    public int AttributeTypeId { get; set; }
    public string AttributeTypeName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}
```

I have below code to Add these new location to database,

```
     private IEnumerable<TEntity> AddEntities<TModel, TEntity, TIdentityType>
     (IEnumerable<TModel> models, Func<TModel, TIdentityType> primaryKey, 
        IGenericRepository<TEntity, TIdentityType> repository)
        {
        var results = new List<TEntity>();

        foreach (var model in models)
        {
            var merged = _mapper.Map<TModel, TEntity>(model);
            var entity = repository.Upsert(merged);
            results.Add(entity);
        }
        repository.Save();
        return results.AsEnumerable();
    }
```

I am using following generic repository to do entity related operations

```
public TEntity Upsert(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (Equals(PrimaryKey.Invoke(entity), default(TId)))
        {
            // New entity
            return Context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
        }
        else
        {
            // Existing entity
            Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            return entity;
        }
    }

   public void Save()
    {
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Whats wrong I am doing here?

Comment: Don't really want to go through your code as it is very extensive, but you are probably missing an `Attach` somewhere.

Comment: can you look in my code for 'Upsert' method and suggest me the right place to use 'Attach'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your suggestions.
I have to get rid of my generic repository here to save my context changes and do it manually as below,

```
private IEnumerable<int> AddLocationEntities(IEnumerable<LocationDataModel> locations)
    {
        var results = new List<int>();
        foreach (LocationDataModel l in locations)
        {
            var entity = _mapper.Map<LocationDataModel, Location>(l);//you can map manually also
            var AttributeCode = l.AssignedAttributes.FirstOrDefault().AttributeTypeId;
            using (MyContext c = new MyContext())
            {
                var attr = c.AttributeTypes.Where(a => a.Id == AttributeTypeId ).ToList();
                entity.AttributeTypes = attr;
                c.Locations.Add(entity);
                c.SaveChanges();
                var locid = entity.Id;
                results.Add(locid);
            }

        }
      return results;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `DbSet<T>.Add()` method attaches an entire object graph as added.  You need to indicate to EF that the 'reference' entity is actually already present.  There are two easy ways to do this:

- Don't set the navigation property to an object.  Instead, just set the corresponding foreign key property to the right value.
- You need to ensure that you don't load multiple instances of the same entity into your object context.  After creating the context, load the full list of `AttributeType` entities into the context and create a `Dictionary<>` to store them.  When you want to add an attribute to a `Location` retrieve the appropriate attribute from the dictionary.  Before calling `SaveChanges()` iterate through the dictionary and mark each `AttributeType` as unchanged.  Something like this:

  ```
      using (MyContext c = new MyContext())
      {
          c.AttributeTypes.Add(new AttributeType { AttributeTypeName = "Fish", AttributeTypeId = 1 });
          c.AttributeTypes.Add(new AttributeType { AttributeTypeName = "Face", AttributeTypeId = 2 });
          c.SaveChanges();
      }

      using (MyContext c = new MyContext())
      {
          Dictionary<int, AttributeType> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, AttributeType>();

          foreach (var t in c.AttributeTypes)
          {
              dictionary[t.AttributeTypeId] = t;
          }

          Location l1 = new Location(1, "Location1") { AttributeTypes = { dictionary[1], dictionary[2] } };
          Location l2 = new Location(2, "Location2") { AttributeTypes = { dictionary[1] } };

          // Because the LocationType is already attached to the context, it doesn't get re-added.
          c.Locations.Add(l1);
          c.Locations.Add(l2);

          c.SaveChanges();
      }
  ```

In this specific case you are using a **many-to-many** relationship, with EF automatically handling the intermediate table.  This means that you don't actually have the FK properties exposed in the model, and my **first suggestion above won't work**.

Therefore, you either need to use the second suggestion, which still ought to work, or you need to forgo the automatic handling of the intermediate table and instead create an entity for it.  This would allow you to apply the first suggestion.  You would have the following model:

```
public partial class Location
{
    public Location()
    {
        this.AttributeTypes = new List<LocationAttribute>();
    }

    public Location(int campusId, string code)
        : this()
    {
        CampusId = campusId; Code = code;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CampusId { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LocationAttribute> AttributeTypes { get; set; }
}

public partial class LocationAttribute
{
    [ForeignKey("LocationId")]
    public Location Location { get; set; }
    public int LocationId { get; set; }

    public int AttributeTypeId { get; set; }
}

public partial class AttributeType
{
    public int AttributeTypeId { get; set; }
    public string AttributeTypeName { get; set; }
}
```

With this approach you do *lose functionality* since you can't navigate from a `Location` to an `AttributeType` without making an intermediate lookup.  If you really want to do that, you need to control the entity state explicitly instead.  (Doing that is not so straightforward when you want to use a generic repository, which is why I've focused on this approach instead.)

Comment: so, do I need to remove navigation property in my 'Location' entity class? and can you advise how to set corresponding foreign key property here?

Comment: "Don't set the navigation property to an object. Instead, just set the corresponding foreign key property to the right value."  - That did it for me.  As soon as I nulled out the navigation properties for the lookup tables, bingo, no more new records in the lookup.  :)

Answer (score 0):

In the `else` statement of your`Upsert` you should add

```
context.TEntity.Attach(entity);
```

Comment: I tried doing attach, it gives below error when I have multiple locations and attribue type is same for all of them. "An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. "

Comment: This will be problematic since you might end up with multiple identical `AttributeType` entities in the context.  See my example for one approach to handling this.